# not getting table data printed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
#from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time


#driver path
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH) 


driver.get("https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed")
print(driver.title)


all_matches=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//label[@analytics-event='All matches']")
all_matches.click()

driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//select[@id='season']/option[@label='20/21']").click()


matches=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//tr')

for match in matches:
    print(match.text)


#driver.quit()
```

terminal

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61934/devtools/browser/30c3f68e-40f3-4a78-b193-d358ba7bbee2
Overs - Total Goals
PS C:\Users\mrmad\Desktop\selenium test> [9208:2332:0731/115957.877:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [11:59:57.877] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[9208:2332:0731/115957.879:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [11:59:57.878] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

using

```
chrome - 103.0.5060.134
chromewebdriver - 103.0.5060.134
python- 3.10.5
selenium - 4.3.0
```

code till select option 20/21 is working
after that i have selected tag (also cross checked in inspect that  have around 760 result so i guess find elements statement is not problem )
please help me print all data in terminal

Comment: tnx webdriverwait() make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select date dropdown option  using Select(). After that, the selected date contains 20 tables. I pull the first table data  as an example using selenium with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1200")


s = Service("./chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

url = 'https://www.adamchoi.co.uk/overs/detailed'
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@analytics-event='All matches']"))).click()

date=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//*[@class="form-group"])[3]/select')))
dropdown= Select(date)
dropdown.select_by_value('object:53')

table_1 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '(//table)[1]'))).get_attribute('outerHTML')
df=pd.read_html(table_1)[0]
print(df)
driver.quit()
```

**Output:**

```
0          1              2                     3
0   13-08-2021       Brentford  2 - 0         Arsenal
1   22-08-2021         Arsenal  0 - 2         Chelsea
2   28-08-2021        Man City  5 - 0         Arsenal
3   11-09-2021         Arsenal  1 - 0         Norwich
4   18-09-2021         Burnley  0 - 1         Arsenal
5   26-09-2021         Arsenal  3 - 1       Tottenham
6   02-10-2021        Brighton  0 - 0         Arsenal
7   18-10-2021         Arsenal  2 - 2  Crystal Palace
8   22-10-2021         Arsenal  3 - 1     Aston Villa
9   30-10-2021       Leicester  0 - 2         Arsenal
10  07-11-2021         Arsenal  1 - 0         Watford
11  20-11-2021       Liverpool  4 - 0         Arsenal
12  27-11-2021         Arsenal  2 - 0       Newcastle
13  02-12-2021      Man United  3 - 2         Arsenal
14  06-12-2021         Everton  2 - 1         Arsenal
15  11-12-2021         Arsenal  3 - 0     Southampton
16  15-12-2021         Arsenal  2 - 0        West Ham
17  18-12-2021           Leeds  1 - 4         Arsenal
18  26-12-2021         Norwich  0 - 5         Arsenal
19  01-01-2022         Arsenal  1 - 2        Man City
20  23-01-2022         Arsenal  0 - 0         Burnley
21  10-02-2022          Wolves  0 - 1         Arsenal
22  19-02-2022         Arsenal  2 - 1       Brentford
23  24-02-2022         Arsenal  2 - 1          Wolves
24  06-03-2022         Watford  2 - 3         Arsenal
25  13-03-2022         Arsenal  2 - 0       Leicester
26  16-03-2022         Arsenal  0 - 2       Liverpool
27  19-03-2022     Aston Villa  0 - 1         Arsenal
28  04-04-2022  Crystal Palace  3 - 0         Arsenal
29  09-04-2022         Arsenal  1 - 2        Brighton
30  16-04-2022     Southampton  1 - 0         Arsenal
31  20-04-2022         Chelsea  2 - 4         Arsenal
32  23-04-2022         Arsenal  3 - 1      Man United
33  01-05-2022        West Ham  1 - 2         Arsenal
34  08-05-2022         Arsenal  2 - 1           Leeds
35  12-05-2022       Tottenham  3 - 0         Arsenal
36  16-05-2022       Newcastle  2 - 0         Arsenal
37  22-05-2022         Arsenal  5 - 1         Everton
```